# Calculate price of array services based on multiple onlick using vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a problem as can be show on the picture balow.On the right I have a list of services which when clicked affects the final price of services on the right.
I have written a code unfortunately it does not work when I click any service on the left.
[image]

**Array of services:**

```
AdditionalServices: [
                {
                    name: 'Web Development',
                    price: 300,
                    short_description:"Detailed comments on the key writing aspects of your paper",
                    long_description:"Get your paper with comprehensive explanations of structure, formatting, and so on, along with precise guidelines for your own writing.",

                    active: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'Design',
                    price: 400,
                    short_description:"Detailed comments on the key writing aspects of your paper",
                    long_description:"Get your paper with comprehensive explanations of structure, formatting, and so on, along with precise guidelines for your own writing.",

                    active: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'Integration',
                    price: 250,
                    short_description:"Detailed comments on the key writing aspects of your paper",
                    long_description:"Get your paper with comprehensive explanations of structure, formatting, and so on, along with precise guidelines for your own writing.",

                    active: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'Training',
                    price: 220,
                    short_description:"Detailed comments on the key writing aspects of your paper",
                    long_description:"Get your paper with comprehensive explanations of structure, formatting, and so on, along with precise guidelines for your own writing.",

                    active: false
                }
            ],
```

**The html code for user interface**

```
<div class="rc-orderform__row rc-orderform__row--additional-features">
   <div class="rc-orderform__feature-heading" data-testid="orderform-additionalServicesTitle">Additional services</div>
   <div class="rc-orderform__feature-body rc-orderform__feature-body--add-features">
      <div class="rc-orderform__feature-body--add-features__item" v-for="service in AdditionalServices">
         <div class="rc-validation-representer valid" data-invalid="false">
            <div class="AdditionalFeature__checkbox filled" data-testid="smartPaperControl">
               <label class="UICheckbox UICheckbox--theme-default">
                  <input id="smart_paper" type="checkbox" class="UICheckbox__checkbox UICheckbox__checkbox--theme-default UICheckbox__checkbox--native" name="smart_paper" v-on:click="toggleActive(service)" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : service.active }" />
                  <div class="UICheckbox__checkbox UICheckbox__checkbox--theme-default UICheckbox__checkbox--faux" tabindex="0"></div>
                  <div class="UICheckbox__label UICheckbox__label--theme--default" for="smart_paper">
                     <div class="AdditionalFeature__label">
                        <div class="AdditionalFeature__header">
                           <div class="AdditionalFeature__title" data-testid="additionalFeature-title">{{service.name}}</div>
                           <div class="AdditionalFeature__price" data-testid="additionalFeature-price"><span>{{service.price}}</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="AdditionalFeature__subtitle" data-testid="additionalFeature-subtitle">{{service.short_description}}</p>
                        <p class="AdditionalFeature__description" data-testid="additionalFeature-description">
                           {{service.long_description}}
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The status toggle method for multiple/single checkbox/The checkbox toggle function**

```
toggleActive: function(s) {
            s.active = !s.active;
        },
```

**The method for calculating cost based on checkbox clicked.Based on the array of prices listed above**

```
calculateTotalAdditionalService() {
            var total = 0;

            //var additional_services=this.AdditionalServices;
            for(let i=0;i<=this.AdditionalServices.length; i++){
                if (i.active){
                    total += i.price;
                }

            }


            return total;
        },
```

**The overall method for calculating overall cost of service**

```
calculateTotal : function (){

               var additional_services =this.calculateTotalAdditionalService();

                var unit_price=Number(parseFloat( additional_services ));

                var amount =(unit_price);

                var sub_total =(amount);

                var total= sub_total;

                return total;

        },
```

Comment: where is checkbox change event callback function?

Comment: @Anilkumar  toggleActive: function(s) {
            s.active = !s.active;
        },

Comment: @Anilkumar its just below the ui code

Comment: @Anilkumar You are uisng checkbox which will be array of values, Not just one boolean. Get check items values which is an array and on calculate just map through array and calcuate the ones that are opted for. You should use `v-model` for this which will contain the checked array values

Comment: @Manjunath thank you though i would appreciate an illustration using code the way I have listed mine.

Comment: @Anilkumar Please create a Codepen or sandbox for the piece of code added above so i can help you further by updating same